# Dagger 2 share single instance of a class between multiple Activities and/or Services

Tags: android, dagger-2

I'm new to Dagger and still learning. I could not figure out how to share a single instance of a class between two Activities or an Activity and a Service.

For example, suppose I have a User class

```
public class User {
    // ...
}
```

and its Module

```
@Module
public class UserModule {
    @UserScope
    @Provides
    User providesUser() {
        return new User();
    }
}
```

and its Component

```
@UserScope
@Component(modules={UserModule.class})
public interface UserComponent {
    // ...
}
```

Now if I have an **ActivityA** and a **ServiceA**, how would I share a single instance of User class between both of them? Also I wan't that single User instance to be released for garbage collection once both the ActivityA and the ServiceA are destroyed. So how would I do this in code?

Comment: and why do you need `dagger2` for that?

Comment: @pskink Since I'm already using dagger2 I thought it would be possible with it.

Comment: what do you want to achieve actually? are activity and service in the same process?

Comment: As I said in the question, share single instance of a class between multiple activities or services and automatically release it for GC once all of the depending activities/services are destroyed.

Comment: are activity and service in the same process?

Comment: Yes, they're in the same process.

Comment: But what about sharing between multiple activities and not services?

Comment: @Jonathan I already read that and could not understand everything, they have created a releaseUserComponent() method that releases the UserComponent. But since I wan't to share it between multiple Activities and the order of their creation/destruction is uncertain, when and where should I call releaseUserComponent()?

Comment: Did you figure out your problem solution?

Comment: @sam_k I just used a WeakReference for storing the UserComponent in the Application class.